# Java EE Deployment Descriptor: What's the benefit of the servlet-name?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

Within the Deployment Descriptor one has to define a "servlet-name" which is later used to map the servlet to some URL-extension.

The example used in a lecture script:

```
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>TestServlet</servlet-class> 
</servlet> 

<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/Servlet1</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

What I don't understand:

Why not mapping the relative path (in relation to the web application folder) of the servlet-class directly to the URL-pattern?

Why not something like ...

```
<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-class>/sources/TestServlet</servlet-class> 
    <url-pattern>/Servlet1</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

... and that's it!

**Why this detour over some "servlet-name"?**

**What's the special benefit of having a "servlet-name" defined?**

Comment: There is no such thing as a "web application folder" in a deployable war file. You're confusing what you have in your development environment, with the standard structure of a war file to deploy on a web server.

Answer (score 0):

Some  reasons for not using something like this

```
<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-class>/sources/TestServlet</servlet-class> 
    <url-pattern>/Servlet1</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

is:

- Threat Protection
- Abstraction